# UIWindow addSubview is not working in ios 9

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, uiwindow

following code working fine in ios 8 ,But in ios 9 i am getting white page with no content.

```
MRForceUpdateView * mForceUpdateView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MRForceUpdateView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

mForceUpdateView.frame = self.view.frame;

UIWindow * window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];

[window addSubview:mForceUpdateView];
```

please suggest a method to add a custom view on app level .

thanks in advance .

Comment: May I ask you why would you want to add a subView on the UIWindow, what is your use case?

Comment: @DevAndArtist i need show server down custom View , if any request failed bcoz of server is down , and user can be on any controller on that time .

Comment: Ok but then your frame calculation in this sample does now make any sense to me. If this is an overlay of top of the same area (the whole screen for example) you could put that view on top everything inside your rootViewController and show it when needed. But I guess you have your own design logic involved there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unchecking "Use Size Classes" option and then coming back and re-checking it again fixes this issue.

- In the project navigator, select a storyboard or xib file.
- The file’s contents open in Interface Builder.
- Choose View > Utilities > Show File Inspector.
- In the Interface Builder Document section, un-tick the "Use Size Classes" checkbox.
- Leave the menu. Come back and tick
  the "Use Size Classes" checkbox again.

Comment: Stupid XCode, I wested my 2 days solving this issue and this solution worked like charm :)

Answer (score 3):

The solution with the size classes is weird to me, because I do not experience any issues for now by adding a subview into the window on iOS 9.

Also i want to point that when the rootViewController is set - all existing views in the window's hierarchy are removed.

From UIWindow documentation:

> The root view controller provides the content view of the window. Assigning a view controller to this property (either programmatically or using Interface Builder) installs the view controller’s view as the content view of the window. If the window has an existing view hierarchy, the old views are removed before the new ones are installed.

So you have to make sure that you add your view into the window hierarchy after the rootViewController is set.

For example when the first controller is loaded - you can lazy load that view only once.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `[window.rootViewController.view addSubview: view];`

Comment: i can't , suppose i am in different controller and i want to show that pop up , if i add on rootviewController then it won't be visible ..

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue & fixed it by simply quitting/force quitting Xcode & Simulator(<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>) & then restarting & Clean (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>). Sometimes Xcode misbehaves, I can only wish I had tried this earlier to save a lot of time.

Answer (score -1):

Try

`view.alpha = 0`

in ViewController and viewDidLoad func

Hope it helps